# SQL: how to check for neither overlapping nor holes in payment records

Tags: sql, join, while-loop, group-by, database-cursor

I do have a table `PaymentSchedules` with percentages info, and dates from/to for which those
percentages are valid, resource by resource:

```
| auto_numbered | res_id | date_start | date_end   | org   | pct |
|---------------+--------+------------+------------+-------+-----|
|             1 | A      | 2018-01-01 | 2019-06-30 | One   | 100 |
|             2 | A      | 2019-07-01 | (NULL)     | One   |  60 |
|             3 | A      | 2019-07-02 | 2019-12-31 | Two   |  40 |
|             4 | A      | 2020-01-01 | (NULL)     | Two   |  40 |
|             5 | B      |     (NULL) | (NULL)     | Three | 100 |
|             6 | C      | 2018-01-01 | (NULL)     | One   | 100 |
|             7 | C      | 2019-11-01 | (NULL)     | Four  | 100 |
```

(Records #3 and #4 could be summarized onto just one line, but duplicated on purpose, to show that there are many combinations of `date_start` and `date_end`.)

A quick reading of the data:

- Org "One" is fully paying for resource A up to 2019-06-30; then, it continues
  to pay 60% of the cost, but the rest (40%) is being paid by org "Two" since
  2019-07-02.

  This should begin on 2019-07-01... small encoding error… provoking a 1-day gap.
- Org "Three" is fully paying for resource B, at all times.
- Org "One" is fully paying for resource C from 2018-01-01... but, starting on
  2019-01-11, org "Four" is paying for it...

  ... and, there, there is an encoding error: we do have 200% of resource C being
  taken into account since 2019-11-01: the record #6 should have been closed
  (`date_end` set to 2019-10-31), but hasn't...

So, when we generate a financial report for the year 2019 (from 2019-01-01 to
2019-12-31), we will have calculation errors...

So, question: **how can we make sure we don't have overlapping payments for
resources, or -- also the contrary -- "holes" for some period of times?**

How is it possible to write an **SQL query** to check that there are neither
underpaid nor overpaid resources?  That is, all resources in the table should be
paid, for **every single day** of the financial period being looked at, by exactly
one or more organizations, in a way that the summed up percentage is always
equal to **100%**.

I don't see how to proceed with such a query. Anybody able to give hints, to put
me on track?

**EDIT --** Working with both SQL Server and Oracle.

**EDIT --** I don't own the DB, I can't add triggers or views. I need to be able to detect things "after the facts"... Need to easily spot the conflictual records, or the "missing" ones (in case of "period holes"), fix them by hand, and then re-run the financial report.

**EDIT --** If we make an analysis for 2019, the following report would be desired:

```
| res_id | pct_sum |       date |
|--------+---------+------------|
| A      |      60 | 2019-07-01 |
| C      |     200 | 2019-11-01 |
| C      |     200 | 2019-11-02 |
| C      |     200 |        ... |
| C      |     200 |        ... |
| C      |     200 |        ... |
| C      |     200 | 2019-12-30 |
| C      |     200 | 2019-12-31 |
```

or, of course, an even much better version -- certainly unobtainable? -- where one
type of problem would one be present once, with the relevant date range for
which the problem is observed:

```
| res_id | pct_sum | date_start |   date_end |
|--------+---------+------------+------------|
| A      |      60 | 2019-07-01 | 2019-07-01 |
| C      |     200 | 2019-11-01 | 2019-12-31 |
```

**EDIT --** Fiddle code: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06d9b7583ccf033eb8ded996f983d7f8)*

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Well, I guess one way is running monthly reports that show the overlaps & holes. So that they become visible before becoming a problem. Or to prevent them, I'm guessing table triggers could check while changing the data.  But then whoever spends their free time on this might wanna know what kind of database & version is used.

Comment: Overlapping payments can easily be prevented in Postgres with a constraint

Comment: @user3341592 . . . I have some understanding of your problem.  But I don't know what you want as results.  Can you show the results in a tabular format in the question?

Comment: If you only focus on the null date_end's it seems easy. F.e. check this *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3adfd85065406eb22c94bd7550b84524)*.  But it'll be more complicated to find gaps between ranges.  Then you might wanna add more bad situations in your sample data to illustrate.

Comment: @LukStorms, thanks for the trial. I do understand your code, and indeed that works for that case, but it's a sub-case of what needs to be reported as errors. Indeed, would the records be closed on 2019-12-31, they still should be reported. And, as you say, this does not cover the gaps.

Comment: Heh, nice that you added that desired report. But only you have access to your data.  So are you expecting that others create the sample data to get that result?  Help others to help you. Btw, why report ('C',200,null) three times?

Comment: @LukStorms, you're totally right. I've updated the Fiddle you've began, with the up-to-date table above.

Comment: ('C', 200, null) is not reported 3 times, it is reported 61 times… once for every problematic day… in the unoptimized report. Does this make sense?

Comment: The fiddles on dbfiddle.uk are versioned.  There's a dropdown with 'markdown' to get a link with your version (at the bottom of the html).  If you closed your version, check your browser history.

Comment: @LukStorms, DONE. Thanks for your help on making the question-answer cycle much simpler for everybody!  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an incomplete attempt for Sql Server.

Basically, the idea was to use a recursive CTE to unfold months for each res_id.

Then left join 'what could be' to the existing date ranges.

But I doubt it can be done in a sql that would work both for Oracle & MS Sql Server.
Sure, both have window functions and CTE's.
But the datetime functions are rarely the same for different RDMS.

So I give up.
Maybe someone else finds an easier solution.

> ```
> create table PaymentSchedules
> (
>   auto_numbered int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   res_id varchar(30),
>   date_start date,
>   date_end date,
>   org varchar(30),
>   pct decimal(3,0)
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into PaymentSchedules
> (res_id, org, pct, date_start, date_end)
> values
>   ('A', 'One',   100, '2018-01-01', '2018-06-30')
> , ('A', 'One',   100, '2019-01-01', '2019-06-30')
> , ('A', 'One',    60, '2019-07-01', null)
> , ('A', 'Two',    40, '2019-07-02', '2019-12-31')
> , ('A', 'Two',    40, '2020-01-01', null)
> , ('B', 'Three', 100, null,         null)
> , ('C', 'One',   100, '2018-01-01', null)
> , ('C', 'Four',  100, '2019-11-01', null)
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> declare @MaxEndDate date;
> set @MaxEndDate = (select max(iif(date_start > date_end, date_start, isnull(date_end, date_start))) from PaymentSchedules);
>
> ;with rcte as
> (
>   select res_id
>   , datefromparts(year(min(date_start)), month(min(date_start)), 1) as month_start
>   , eomonth(coalesce(max(date_end), @MaxEndDate)) as month_end
>   , 0 as lvl
>   from PaymentSchedules
>   group by res_id
>   having min(date_start) is not null
>
>   union all
>
>   select res_id
>   , dateadd(month, 1, month_start)
>   , month_end
>   , lvl + 1
>   from rcte
>   where dateadd(month, 1, month_start) < month_end
> )
> , cte_gai as
> (
> select c.res_id, c.month_start, c.month_end
> , t.org, t.pct, t.auto_numbered
> , sum(isnull(t.pct,0)) over (partition by c.res_id, c.month_start) as res_month_pct
> , count(t.auto_numbered) over (partition by c.res_id, c.month_start) as cnt
> from rcte c
> left join PaymentSchedules t
>   on t.res_id = c.res_id
>  and c.month_start >= datefromparts(year(t.date_start), month(t.date_start), 1)
>  and c.month_start <= coalesce(t.date_end, @MaxEndDate)
> )
> select *
> from cte_gai
> where res_month_pct <> 100
> order by res_id, month_start
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> res_id | month_start | month_end  | org  | pct  | auto_numbered | res_month_pct | cnt
> :----- | :---------- | :--------- | :--- | :--- | ------------: | :------------ | --:
> A      | 2018-07-01  | 2019-12-31 | null | null |          null | 0             |   0
> A      | 2018-08-01  | 2019-12-31 | null | null |          null | 0             |   0
> A      | 2018-09-01  | 2019-12-31 | null | null |          null | 0             |   0
> A      | 2018-10-01  | 2019-12-31 | null | null |          null | 0             |   0
> A      | 2018-11-01  | 2019-12-31 | null | null |          null | 0             |   0
> A      | 2018-12-01  | 2019-12-31 | null | null |          null | 0             |   0
> C      | 2019-11-01  | 2020-01-31 | One  | 100  |             7 | 200           |   2
> C      | 2019-11-01  | 2020-01-31 | Four | 100  |             8 | 200           |   2
> C      | 2019-12-01  | 2020-01-31 | One  | 100  |             7 | 200           |   2
> C      | 2019-12-01  | 2020-01-31 | Four | 100  |             8 | 200           |   2
> C      | 2020-01-01  | 2020-01-31 | One  | 100  |             7 | 200           |   2
> C      | 2020-01-01  | 2020-01-31 | Four | 100  |             8 | 200           |   2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a7edda940e2ae1064dacae8d6710216)*

Answer (score -2):

I am not giving the full answer here but I think that you are after cursors(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

This allows you to iterate through the database, checking all of the records.

This is bad practice because even though the idea is really good, they are quite heavy, and they are slow, and they block the involved tables.

I know some people have found a method to rewrite cursors using loops (while probably), so you need to understand a cursor, get how you would implement it and then translate it into a loop. (https://www.sqlbook.com/advanced/sql-cursors-how-to-avoid-them/)

Also, views can be helpful, but I am assuming that you know how to use them already.

The algorithm should be something like:
 have table1 and table2 (table2 is a copy of table1, https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/sql-tutorial/sql-cloning-tables.php)

1. iterate through all of the records (I would use in the first instance a cursor for this) from table1. Picking up a record from table1.
2. if overlapping dates (check it against table2) do something
3. else do something else
4. pick another record from table1 and go to step 2.
5. Drop unnecessary tables

Comment: That's the thing: how would we write the SQL statement of the view?  I don't see the light yet...

Comment: have you checked what a cursor does? I thought you did not know how to iterate through the records, and that was your question

Comment: You mean iterate through all dates at step 1?  Check out for 2019-01-01, then for 2019-01-02, and so on?  Then step 0 would be to compute a list/array (dunno the exact term) of all dates to be checked?

Comment: added clarification

Comment: How to you copy table1?  May not have rights for creating a table in TEMP?  Not sure to follow...

Comment: you need to copy the tables because the record will have to be checked against the table itself, but the table is locked (cursors), so you need a second table (one that is not locked). What kind of permissions do you have?

Comment: There is probably another way, much easier, to do it, but I can't think of